# Trivia game using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a trivia game using jquery and javascript. I'm having trouble with the code. I already able to display the first question but now I don't know how to approach the rest of the question. I want the next question and answers to display without needing the user input and continue to display until there is no more question left. Each question have a timer of 30 seconds.

```
var userPick;

var correctAnswer = 0;

var incorrectAnswer = 0;

var unAnswer = 0;

var question = 0;

var images;

var count=30;

var disneyQuestion = [{
question: "In Aladdin, what is the name of Jasmine's pet tiger?",
choices: ["Rajah", "Bo", "Iago", "Jack" ],
images:  ["../images/Rajah.gif"],
validAnswer: 0
}, {
question:"In Peter Pan, Captain Hook had a hook on which part of his     body?",
choices: ["Right Foot", "Left Hand", "Left Foot", "Right Hand"],
validAnswer: 1

}, {
question:"In the Lion King, where does Mufasa and his family live?",
choices: ["Rocky Mountain", "Forest", "Desert", "Pride Rock"],
validAnswer: 3

}, {
question:"In Beauty and the Beast, how many eggs does Gaston eat for    breakfast?",
choices: ["2 Dozen", "5 Dozen", "5000", "0"],
validAnswer: 1

}, {
question:"In Alice in Wonderland, what is the name of Alice’s kitten?",
choices: ["Dinah", "Sammie", "Kat", "Luna"],
validAnswer: 0

 }, {
question:"After being on earth, where did Hercules first meet his   father Zeus?",
choices: ["Mount Olympus", "Greece", "In the Temple of Zeus", "Elysian   Fields"],
validAnswer: 2

}, {
question:"During the ballroom scene of Beauty & the Beast, what color is Belle’s Gown?",
choices: ["Yellow", "Blue", "Gold", "White"],
validAnswer: 2

}, {
question:"In Bambi, what word does the owl use to describe falling in love?",
choices: ["Whimsical", "Miserable", "Joyful", "Twitterpatted"],
validAnswer: 3

}

];

$("#start_button").click(function(){
$(this).hide();
counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); 
displayTrivia();
}); 


function timer(){
count--;
if (count <= 0) {
 clearInterval(counter);
 return;
}

 $("#timer").html("Time remaining: " + "00:" + count + " secs");
}


function displayTrivia() {
$("#question_div").html(disneyQuestion[0].question);
question++;

  var choicesArr = disneyQuestion[0].choices;
  var buttonsArr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < choicesArr.length; i++) {
    var button = $('<button>');
    button.text(choicesArr[i]);
    button.attr('data-id', i);
    $('#choices_div').append(button);
   }

  } 

 $('#choices_div').on('click', 'button', function(e){
 userPick = $(this).data("id");
 disneyQuestion[0].validAnswer;
 if(userPick != disneyQuestion[0].validAnswer) {

 $('#choices_div').text("Wrong Answer! The correct answer is Rajah.");
 incorrectAnswer++;

} else if (userPick === disneyQuestion[0].validAnswer) {
$('#choices_div').text("Correct!!! The pet tiger name is Rajah");
correctAnswer++;

}

});
```

Comment: In its current form your question is missing a [mcve]. Please see [ask] for advice on how to improve the quality of your question so it becomes answerable.

Comment: As you pull together that "Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example", you might also consider calling your `displayTrivia()` function with a parameter `questionNum` that is the `current question #`, and replacing the hard coded [0] with that - `disneyQuestion[questionNum].question`, and `disneyQuestion[questionNum].choices`.  You are on the right track...

Comment: perfect, thank you and I'm still new to stackoverflow so sorry about the the way I ask question. I will improve that. Appreciate your help!!

Comment: In addition to @rasmeister's suggestion, what you need is a function that controls the asking/answering process. It should run a `for` loop on the array of questions (or `$.each` - since you use `jQuery`) and call `disneyQuestion(n)` with the current question index as param. In `disneyQuestion()` you will need to replace the `[0]`'s with this `[n]` and it should return when the question was resolved (by timer or answer) and next question should be called. That's the principle. But please do add the markup, so we have a working example.

Comment: I will look into that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I liked the idea so here it is. It could be optimized and streamlined a bit more, and has no styling.

Took your logic and packed it up as a `jQuery` plugin, mainly because this way it's contained inside a single variable, which could be easily replaced with a new instance of it, when the user restarts.

```js
$.fn.trivia = function() {
    var _t = this;
    _t.userPick = null;
    _t.answers = {
        correct: 0,
        incorrect: 0
    };
    _t.images = null;
    _t.count = 30;
    _t.current = 0;
    _t.questions = [{
        question: "In Aladdin, what is the name of Jasmine's pet tiger?",
        choices: ["Rajah", "Bo", "Iago", "Jack"],
        images: ["../images/Rajah.gif"],
        correct: 0
    }, {
        question: "In Peter Pan, Captain Hook had a hook on which part of his     body?",
        choices: ["Right Foot", "Left Hand", "Left Foot", "Right Hand"],
        correct: 1

    }, {
        question: "In the Lion King, where does Mufasa and his family live?",
        choices: ["Rocky Mountain", "Forest", "Desert", "Pride Rock"],
        correct: 3

    }, {
        question: "In Beauty and the Beast, how many eggs does Gaston eat for    breakfast?",
        choices: ["2 Dozen", "5 Dozen", "5000", "0"],
        correct: 1

    }, {
        question: "In Alice in Wonderland, what is the name of Alice’s kitten?",
        choices: ["Dinah", "Sammie", "Kat", "Luna"],
        correct: 0

    }, {
        question: "After being on earth, where did Hercules first meet his   father Zeus?",
        choices: ["Mount Olympus", "Greece", "In the Temple of Zeus", "Elysian   Fields"],
        correct: 2

    }, {
        question: "During the ballroom scene of Beauty & the Beast, what color is Belle’s Gown?",
        choices: ["Yellow", "Blue", "Gold", "White"],
        correct: 2

    }, {
        question: "In Bambi, what word does the owl use to describe falling in love?",
        choices: ["Whimsical", "Miserable", "Joyful", "Twitterpatted"],
        correct: 3
    }];
    _t.ask = function() {
        if (_t.questions[_t.current]) {
            $("#timer").html("Time remaining: " + "00:" + _t.count + " secs");
            $("#question_div").html(_t.questions[_t.current].question);
            var choicesArr = _t.questions[_t.current].choices;
            var buttonsArr = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < choicesArr.length; i++) {
                var button = $('<button>');
                button.text(choicesArr[i]);
                button.attr('data-id', i);
                $('#choices_div').append(button);
            }
            window.triviaCounter = setInterval(_t.timer, 1000);
        } else {
            $('body').append($('<div />', {
                text: 'Unanswered: ' + (
                    _t.questions.length - (_t.answers.correct + _t.answers.incorrect)),
                class: 'result'
            }));
            $('#start_button').text('Restart').appendTo('body').show();
        }
    };
    _t.timer = function() {
        _t.count--;
        if (_t.count <= 0) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                _t.nextQ();
            });

        } else {
            $("#timer").html("Time remaining: " + "00:" + _t.count + " secs");
        }
    };
    _t.nextQ = function() {
        _t.current++;
        clearInterval(window.triviaCounter);
        _t.count = 30;
        $('#timer').html("");
        setTimeout(function() {
            _t.cleanUp();
            _t.ask();
        }, 1000)
    };
    _t.cleanUp = function() {
        $('div[id]').each(function(item) {
            $(this).html('');
        });
        $('.correct').html('Correct answers: ' + _t.answers.correct);
        $('.incorrect').html('Incorrect answers: ' + _t.answers.incorrect);
    };
    _t.answer = function(correct) {
        var string = correct ? 'correct' : 'incorrect';
        _t.answers[string]++;
        $('.' + string).html(string + ' answers: ' + _t.answers[string]);
    };
    return _t;
};
var Trivia;

$("#start_button").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.result').remove();
    $('div').html('');
    Trivia = new $(window).trivia();
    Trivia.ask();
});

$('#choices_div').on('click', 'button', function(e) {
    var userPick = $(this).data("id"),
        _t = Trivia || $(window).trivia(),
        index = _t.questions[_t.current].correct,
        correct = _t.questions[_t.current].choices[index];

    if (userPick !== index) {
        $('#choices_div').text("Wrong Answer! The correct answer was: " + correct);
        _t.answer(false);
    } else {
        $('#choices_div').text("Correct!!! The correct answer was: " + correct);
        _t.answer(true);
    }
    _t.nextQ();
});
```

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.correct, .incorrect {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start_button">start game</button>
<div id="timer"></div>
<div id="question_div"></div>
<div id="choices_div"></div>
<div class="correct"></div>
<div class="incorrect"></div>
```

Feel free to extend and style it up, add features, questions.